# Change the value of a pandas dataframe column based on a condition ,also depending on other columns of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    Category              DishName   Id 
0   a                     Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
1   a                     Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
2   a                     Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
3   a                     achar      621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
4   b                     achar      621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
5   b                     achar      621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
6   a                     chicken    621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
7   b                     chicken    621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
8   c                     chicken    621f4884e48bc60012364b13
```

My dataframe has 3 columns category, dishname and id. Considering the id and the dishname I have to assign category.

Assign "a" if all the category values are "a"

Assign "b" if category values are "a","b"

Assign "c" if category values are "a","b","c"

Expected output is

```
    Category              DishName   Id 
0   a                     Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
1   a                     Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
2   a                     Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
3   b                     achar      621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
4   b                     achar      621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
5   b                     achar      621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
6   c                     chicken    621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
7   c                     chicken    621f4884e48bc60012364b13   
8   c                     chicken    621f4884e48bc60012364b13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform to ordered Categorical and get the max per group:

```
df['Category'] = (pd
                  .Series(pd.Categorical(df['Category'],
                                         categories=['a', 'b', 'c'], ordered=True),
                          index=df.index)
                  .groupby(df['DishName'])
                  .transform('max')
                  )
```

*NB. You wouldn't need the categorical for simply `a, b, c`, as those three are lexicographically sorted, but I imagine a real life case wouldn't necessarily be. As example `low < medium < high` is logically but not lexicographically sorted.*

Output:

```
  Category   DishName                        Id
0        a  Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
1        a  Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
2        a  Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
3        b      achar  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
4        b      achar  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
5        b      achar  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
6        c    chicken  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
7        c    chicken  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
8        c    chicken  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
```

Comment: What if i need to consider the column Id also in groupby? ie both Id and DishName

Comment: I tried the same, but giving me key error

Comment: My bad, `groupby([df['DishName'], df ['Id']])`

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Category'] = df.groupby('DishName')['Category'].transform('max')
```

Output:

```
  Category   DishName                        Id
0        a  Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
1        a  Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
2        a  Pistachio  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
3        b      achar  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
4        b      achar  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
5        b      achar  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
6        c    chicken  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
7        c    chicken  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
8        c    chicken  621f4884e48bc60012364b13
```

Comment: As I detailed in my answer, this likely works here by "chance". OP probably has more complex categories, not necessarily lexicographically sorted, in the real life data.

Comment: I agree, yours is the more robust method, mine just happens to work in this specific case. @mozway

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong and this is really a/b/c :p

Comment: You never know with these :')